# How i can do download file from database using CodeIgniter based on the file id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$this->load->helper('download');

//get file info from database
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$fileInfo['gambar'] = $this->mod_surat_masuk->download($id);

//download file from directory
$file = 'gambar_product'.$file['gambar'];
force_download($file, NULL);
```

that my code but didn't work anyway
so how can I make download function using Codeigniter based on the file id?

Comment: `echo $file; die;` and post data

Comment: please echo $file and tell me which path display on $file?

Comment: the path is the directory im upload the file.....

or if u guys got some code that similiar to my problem
please kindly post it here Thx

Comment: need output, not your opinion buddy in order to help

Comment: what is `$fileInfo['gambar']` returning (like echo the actual output and post here)? also I'm pretty sure `force_download` requires a full path so something like `image/somefile.jpg` wont work has to be `/var/www/html/image/somefile.jpg` (full path + root)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
$this->load->helper('download');
//get file info from database
$id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$fileInfo = $this->mod_surat_masuk->download($id);

$source_file = file_get_contents(base_url() . 'gambar_product/' . $fileInfo['NAME_OF_THE_FILE']);
$file_name = $fileInfo['NAME_OF_THE_FILE'];
ob_clean();
force_download($file_name, $source_file);
?>
```

Comment: i try to download file based on the file id on databse, not fixed file @Pathik Venjani

Comment: what is the file name? @RizkiKurniawan

Comment: @Phatik Venjani Thx it worked, but when i try to download and open the file was corrupt or something

Comment: is it pdf or what?

Comment: jpg and also pdf

Comment: write ob_clean(); before force_download(); @RizkiKurniawan see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter has a nice helper function to download files.

```
public function download ($file_path = ""){
    // load ci download helder
    $this->load->helper('download');  

    // get download file path and store it in $data array
    $data['download_file'] = $file_path;  

    // load view file    
    $this->load->view("download_view",$data);
    redirect(current_url(), "refresh");                       
}
```

In view section (`download_view.php`), just call the download function that's it.

```
if(! empty($download_file))
{
    $data = file_get_contents(base_url("/path/".$download_file)); 
    // Read the file's contents
    $name = $download_file;
    force_download($name, $data);
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76: please don't add code formatting to names of software, libraries or languages. In writing terms they are just proper nouns, and so the usual thing to correct here is case. However, filenames are often formatted as general computer I/O, so if you see those, they can be backticked.